# django classbased view not accepting view_args and view_kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-middleware

I am using django 1.8. I am using `django.views.generic.View` class in one of my View.

```
class CommonView(View):
    func_name = 'view_func'
    http_method_names = ["get", "post"]
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'template.html', {})
```

in urls.py i added

```
url(r'^common/$',CommonView),
```

I have written a middleware where i am doing some work with view response and overridden `process_view` method

```
class CommonMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
        """ Do something"""
        return response
```

but in this line `response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)` I am getting error

```
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/common/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

and before it I have to check the `func_name` of the view function. But in the middle ware class when i am trying to get the `func_name` attribute from `view_func` at that time I am getting an `AttributeError` that `CommonView has no attribute func_name` whereas I am getting it from all the function based views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in this line

```
url(r'^common/$',CommonView),
```

you have to use

```
url(r'^common/$',CommonView.as_view()),
```

you forgot to add `as_view()` with your class based view while calling it from urls

Comment: ahhh, it is a silly mistake. spent couple of hours for finding the error.